# How do I have the deletion of a user in Django trigger execution of some additional code?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

In my Django application, when a user is created, a database is created too. This is defined in my registration view. I have the database creation to make up for the lack of support for dynamic models. My problem is that I want to have the deletion of a user in the Django admin page call some code which will also delete the database. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what code you want to call, consider [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-delete) as an option, if it doesn't metter for you where object being deleted or overriding [delete_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_model) method, in case you want to run this code specifically during delete via admin.